# Deleting primary key from database

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

In my database I have two tables, `Orders` and `Items`. If I insert two orders with ID 1 and 2 and then delete the second one then my next ID will be 3. This I understand, I'm also aware that I shouldn't interfere with primary keys in my tables. But what's bugging me if there really isn't some way to shrink ID so when I delete ID 2 then next time when I add some order to my database I will like for it to be placed on ID 2. Autonumber then falls of or?

I've probably done it the wrong way because I'm getting my order in this function:

```
 Private Sub GetLastOrderID()
    Try
        sqL = "SELECT ID FROM Order ORDER BY ID Desc"
        ConnDB()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

        'next id in database is current + 1
        If dr.Read = True Then
            txtOrderID.Text = dr("ID") + 1
        Else
            txtidnarocila.Text = 1
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

So in general I have problem when I delete Order on some ID then program does not know that there is missing ID. When I delete ID 2, my code still sees only one ID in database and again I have "next id" as 2. But In database is 3.

Asking for some instructions. Thank you.

Comment: Is your ID an autonumber field?

Comment: When you insert a record into the database it will assign the ID and order number for you (assuming this is an autonumber).  Then you should query the database to find out what the order number is.  Selecting an order number in code and having the database do it as well will create conflicts

Comment: Will I solve this problem with some junction table? Since I shouldn't delete primary keys...

Answer (score 0):

The next id is not necessarily the last one plus one , due to, as you have discovered, the fact that MS Access manages the auto number column on its own. Moreover, you could also have problems in multiuser scenarios where two users could select the same last key,  increment it and end up with conflicting keys.
To determine the last inserted key, use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

No matter what you do, autonumbers or otherwise, deletions will always cause gaps that are not worth writing code to close.

Comment: Should I SELECT @@IDENTITY after I'm using INSERT? I've tried it with only SELECT @@IDENTITY when I had database connection open and it returns 0, regardles how many items I already have in my table.

Comment: Yes. After the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to restructure this as getNextOrderId() instead:

```
Private Sub GetLastOrderID()
   int currentId = 0
   Try
    sqL = "SELECT ID FROM Order ORDER BY ID"

    //Stripped out connection handling
    //execute SQL

    while (dr.Read = True) {
        txtOrderID.Text = dr("ID")
        if (txtOrderID.Text > currentId +1)
           txtOrderID.Text = currentId + 1
           break
        else
           currentId++
    }

    End Try
End Sub
```

Of course this could take a lot of time as the number of orders increase.  If you have to fill in all the order numbers you are kind of stuck, otherwise it might be easiest to just skip the gaps, or mark them as cancelled orders.